# ggplot2 line plot for a subset of the data

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I have some dataset, lets call it `plot_data_lines` looking like this:

```
|Year  |City       |value  |
-----------------------------
|1981  |Bogota     |4      |
|1981  |Cali       |3      |
|1981  |Lima       |2      |
|1981  |Sao Paulo  |1      |
|1981  |Santiago   |6      |
|1982  |Bogota     |4      |
|1982  |Cali       |2      |
|1982  |Lima       |1      |
|1982  |Sao Paulo  |0      |
|1982  |Santiago   |4      |
|1983  |Bogota     |3      |
|1983  |Cali       |4      |
|1983  |Lima       |1      |
|1983  |Sao Paulo  |6      |
|1983  |Santiago   |6      |
|...   |...        |...    |
|2020  |Bogota     |5      |
|2020  |Cali       |7      |
|2020  |Lima       |9      |
|2020  |Sao Paulo  |1      |
|2020  |Santiago   |3      |
```

It is already in long format and when i ask for the class of the dataset this is what i get:

```
> class(plot_data_lines)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

What i need i to make a line plot of a subset of the cities, for example: Cali, Bogota and Lima, but not necessarily these, and not necessarily only three, and this is what I've tried:

```
plot_data_lines %>%
  filter(City %in% c("Lima", "Bogota","Cali)) %>%
  ggplot(plot_data_bar, aes(x = "Year", y = value, color = City)) +
  geom_line()
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in `ggplot()`:
! Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

What went wrong? Can you guys help me?

Edit: This is the plot that I get with Allan Camero's recomendation:

[image]

What went wrong this time?

This is a sample of my data in order to be reproducible:

```
structure(list(Year = c("1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", 
"1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", 
"1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", 
"1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", 
"1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", 
"1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", "1981", 
"1981", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", 
"1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", 
"1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", 
"1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", 
"1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", 
"1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1982", "1983", 
"1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", 
"1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", 
"1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", 
"1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", 
"1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", 
"1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1983", "1984", "1984", "1984", 
"1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", 
"1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", 
"1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", 
"1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", 
"1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", "1984", 
"1984", "1984", "1984"), City = c("Sao Paulo", "Mexico City", 
"Lima", "Bogota", "Rio de Janeiro", "Santiago", "Caracas", "Buenos Aires", 
"San Salvador", "Brasilia", "Fortaleza", "Guayaquil", "Quito", 
"Belo Horizonte", "Medellin", "Cali", "Havana", "Manaus", "Curitiba", 
"Maracaibo", "Recife", "Santa Cruz", "Porto Alegre", "Guadalajara", 
"Belem", "Puebla", "Goiania", "Cordoba", "Juarez", "Montevideo", 
"Leon de los Aldama", "Tijuana", "Barranquilla", "Tegucigalpa", 
"Campinas", "Barquisimeto", "Monterrey", "Sao Luis", "Managua", 
"Ciudad Nezahualcoyotl", "Maceio", "Callao", "Santo Domingo", 
"Guatemala City", "Port-au-Prince", "Rosario", "Sao Paulo", "Mexico City", 
"Lima", "Bogota", "Rio de Janeiro", "Santiago", "Caracas", "Buenos Aires", 
"San Salvador", "Brasilia", "Fortaleza", "Guayaquil", "Quito", 
"Belo Horizonte", "Medellin", "Cali", "Havana", "Manaus", "Curitiba", 
"Maracaibo", "Recife", "Santa Cruz", "Porto Alegre", "Guadalajara", 
"Belem", "Puebla", "Goiania", "Cordoba", "Juarez", "Montevideo", 
"Leon de los Aldama", "Tijuana", "Barranquilla", "Tegucigalpa", 
"Campinas", "Barquisimeto", "Monterrey", "Sao Luis", "Managua", 
"Ciudad Nezahualcoyotl", "Maceio", "Callao", "Santo Domingo", 
"Guatemala City", "Port-au-Prince", "Rosario", "Sao Paulo", "Mexico City", 
"Lima", "Bogota", "Rio de Janeiro", "Santiago", "Caracas", "Buenos Aires", 
"San Salvador", "Brasilia", "Fortaleza", "Guayaquil", "Quito", 
"Belo Horizonte", "Medellin", "Cali", "Havana", "Manaus", "Curitiba", 
"Maracaibo", "Recife", "Santa Cruz", "Porto Alegre", "Guadalajara", 
"Belem", "Puebla", "Goiania", "Cordoba", "Juarez", "Montevideo", 
"Leon de los Aldama", "Tijuana", "Barranquilla", "Tegucigalpa", 
"Campinas", "Barquisimeto", "Monterrey", "Sao Luis", "Managua", 
"Ciudad Nezahualcoyotl", "Maceio", "Callao", "Santo Domingo", 
"Guatemala City", "Port-au-Prince", "Rosario", "Sao Paulo", "Mexico City", 
"Lima", "Bogota", "Rio de Janeiro", "Santiago", "Caracas", "Buenos Aires", 
"San Salvador", "Brasilia", "Fortaleza", "Guayaquil", "Quito", 
"Belo Horizonte", "Medellin", "Cali", "Havana", "Manaus", "Curitiba", 
"Maracaibo", "Recife", "Santa Cruz", "Porto Alegre", "Guadalajara", 
"Belem", "Puebla", "Goiania", "Cordoba", "Juarez", "Montevideo", 
"Leon de los Aldama", "Tijuana", "Barranquilla", "Tegucigalpa", 
"Campinas", "Barquisimeto", "Monterrey", "Sao Luis", "Managua", 
"Ciudad Nezahualcoyotl", "Maceio", "Callao", "Santo Domingo", 
"Guatemala City", "Port-au-Prince", "Rosario"), value = c(-0.00752411164965841, 
-0.00858235806970273, -0.0193390181364576, -0.0254733683434182, 
-0.0135609910986883, 0.105134246948455, -0.00327911235803224, 
0.02163440097074, -0.0079795250800731, -0.0120663651057852, 0.00566322468255433, 
-0.00977488904664624, -0.0168848675316369, -0.0196401016591058, 
-0.0192114068827001, -0.0128140808793732, -0.014223152965439, 
-0.00973446424945887, 0.0375699418169768, -0.02142105793661, 
-0.00695816631860418, 0.0110692713467446, 0.0459416198602932, 
-0.00522005746178392, 0.0117604524786534, -0.0171166573772657, 
-0.0224270599445623, 0.0568574598072727, 0.363782440715696, 0.00176871008818945, 
0.00615268511881207, 0.0218960489961891, -0.00677296734458201, 
0.00848375774004822, -0.00592202637837714, -0.00823049786018653, 
0.0654160956549713, 0.00655848522936036, -0.00811797806585994, 
-0.00759894252446815, -0.0101038496148005, -0.0192750800973933, 
-0.00774381271740157, -0.00270769939926697, -0.0115319737226118, 
0.067601746659629, 0.0412887465245744, 0.0675304707144076, 0.049352729240842, 
-0.00515059960494002, 0.0118978209360105, 0.0532868362072011, 
-0.0138900894067038, 0.0553103203820288, 0.0144467932412351, 
0.0230619422362681, -0.00768032309305345, 0.0295175710261359, 
0.0291436275702546, 0.0334635285240448, 0.00297185628988496, 
0.00860089159697064, 0.0418153705968756, 0.00884665494515552, 
0.0567507349024041, 0.0115747255551046, 0.00494974302483174, 
0.0222767386344832, 0.0410441639217649, 0.0339220986643466, -0.00851634191144674, 
0.032073082124077, 0.0150209385609767, 0.0917094854315508, 0.136101721332058, 
0.050368267606148, 0.0704829723767993, -0.0392054869667851, 0.000438081167034402, 
0.00922131908379296, 0.0250832686146108, -0.0160053135734178, 
0.105575686170073, -0.00770350237506892, 0.0185934426465312, 
0.0622439535708169, 0.007220419413762, 0.0556334333005619, -0.0169255561672605, 
0.0204398042931697, -0.00776762518081134, 0.0723950051880403, 
0.020920878349233, -0.00995206377715023, 0.0929229547913617, 
0.0228930063871382, 0.00842649575171037, -0.0425511033876532, 
0.0473487675635951, -0.0093536731191666, 0.00856150354267576, 
6.2395130758288e-05, 0.0180391647982547, 0.00166767498637137, 
-0.00860498608682273, 0.0105366504728758, 0.00343173349545559, 
-0.00792009126743003, -0.019685205307497, 0.0196050922389284, 
0.0219901276461645, 0.0189481802235595, 0.0138318843795572, -0.00365097545580035, 
-0.0166818970244572, -0.0479954584836083, 0.0184171924206671, 
-0.0176179306226417, 0.000719905928180277, -0.00772610628525053, 
0.0235675832224525, -0.0158458659538299, -0.0405076597339783, 
0.0531548160747947, 0.00775762163745756, 0.026232494634189, 0.0130544024464169, 
0.0467360166589372, 0.0193387856213601, 0.0191346924219357, 0.0251196408085357, 
-0.0118308797174065, 0.0125649925727593, 0.0979136729415388, 
0.0232545093007293, 0.00307768553311674, 0.0308309002997723, 
-0.0158154410745328, 0.0304899632424906, -0.0230856315886497, 
-0.113105853584711, -0.061531343276225, 0.0243821742105042, 0.15741352761236, 
-0.0266363954419561, 0.00930455151957403, -0.0352929141002193, 
0.0117437323008912, -0.0177357806200151, -0.0533701909768894, 
-0.0723079488380151, 0.0349916330912371, -0.0541181208042864, 
-0.034948153391848, -0.000224652317719612, -0.0338468457314207, 
0.0481618504964105, -0.0161638266039731, -0.000296376579238326, 
0.0431739523962326, 0.0433822174484497, 0.0169865188027782, -0.0287180945332731, 
-0.0206794881498912, 0.0142301430755713, 0.033694331269516, -0.446442104059541, 
0.00959839940203957, 0.0161915348613291, 0.0114643674721635, 
-0.0244942682854959, -0.0382169511934245, 0.0403839854108356, 
-0.00260313570491377, -0.202768982864469, -0.0273731843762094, 
-0.0320431601672718, -0.0219882334689516, 0.00146763256941326, 
-0.122515996840899, -0.0172163590871104, -0.027759749062993, 
-0.0226039983152669, 0.0242689613566711)), row.names = c(NA, 
-184L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You have piped your data set through to ggplot, meaning that you are passing the filtered `plot_data_lines` object as the first argument to `ggplot`. However, you are also passing in `plot_data_bar`, so `ggplot` thinks you are trying to use that to set aesthetic mapping. Try `ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, color = City))` . Note that `"Year"` shouldn't have quotes. It should just be `Year`

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you say for the subset ("Bogota","Lima"), and I don't get any error but the plot is just a vertical line as I show you in the original question

Comment: That's because you didn't remove the double quotes as I suggested. See my answer below

Comment: I saw my error, but with my data, which I share in the question, The plot did not show any line...

Comment: Your `Year` column is stored as character format rather than numbers. It just needs converted (we can do this inside the plotting code). Please see my update for a solution that works with your actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
plot_data_lines %>%
  filter(City %in% c("Lima", "Bogota","Cali")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Year), y = value, color = City)) +
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x = "Year")
```

[image]

You will get a vertical line if you put `x = "Year"` instead of `x = Year`:

```r
plot_data_lines %>%
  filter(City %in% c("Lima", "Bogota","Cali")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "Year", y = value, color = City)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]